# Есть ли принципиальные отличия в вызове echo со скобками и без? echo $a или echo ($a)

Tags: php, синтаксис, echo

Есть ли разница между

```
echo $mass['error'][$z];
```

и

```
echo ($mass['error'][$z]);
```

Где-то я читал что если что-то в скобках, то на уровне php происходит какая-то раскапсуляция(?). Если бы было без скобок, то php вывел бы значение, а если в скобках, то сначала что-то происходит (типа вычисление(?)), а потом происходит вывод. Хотя и в первом случае и во втором то же самое. Или это делает парсер php?

Comment: в даном примере никакой

Comment: это я знаю. но все-таки где-то я читал что если что-то в скобках, то на уровне php происходит какая-то раскапсуляция(?). Если бы было без скобок, то php вывел бы значение, а если в скобках, то сначала что-то происходит (типа вычисление(?)), а потом происходит вывод. Хотя и в первом случае и во втором то же самое. Или это делает парсер php. Не знаю, потому и спрашиваю.

Comment: Какое это отношение к Си имеет?

Comment: я о Си никогда ничего, нигде, не спрашивал.

Answer (score 2):

Так как `echo` - это не функция, не имеет значения используете вы скобки или нет. PHP их просто проигнорирует.

Можно посмотреть какие опкоды получаются если использовать скобки, и если нет:

- https://3v4l.org/ZdT4b/vld#output
- https://3v4l.org/lsr9l/vld#output

Легко увидеть что опкоды (то есть результат компиляции) в том и другом случае те же самые. Никакой разницы используемые скобки не привносят, но лучше придерживаться существующей практике и не ставить их, если для этого нет особой причины.